# Comparing iterators of arrays with same size

Tags: c++, arrays, iterator, compare, predicate

Let's say I have 2 arrays of same size:

```cpp
std::array<int,3> a{2,4,8};
std::array<int,3> b{1,2,3};
```

I want to know whether `a > b` saying **`a` is greater than `b`, if and only if each element at certain index `i` in `a` is greater then the element at the same index in `b`**.

Now, I want to implement this idea using iterators:

```cpp
std::compare(a.begin(),a.end(),b.begin(),[&](const int& first,const int& second) {return first > second;}
```

I've read about `std::lexicographical_compare` with its `_Compare` argument, but this comparison does not meet my goals.

Is there a compare function like I wrote? Or, how can I create my own?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, but what you describe does sound like a lexicographical ordering. Can you explain why `std::lexicographical_compare` is not what you want? Maybe add examples. What result do you expect for `a < b` for the two arrays in your question?

Comment: ok I now understand that it isnt a lexicographical ordering, but still some examples would help to understand. Also it is not clear what you mean with `std::compare` afaik there no std algorithm with that name

Comment: `std::lexicographical_compare` fails because it returns true if `a[0] > b[0] ` but it shall compare other elements too...

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I know that there is no such function, but can I achieve that using other functions or write my own??

Comment: As I understand your comparison, care as it doesn't seem to respect strict weak ordering.

Comment: strictly speaking no. You are not allowed to add something to the `std` namespace (with few exceptions), you can of course write a `my_cool_namespace_name::compare` ;)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in a comment, a warning is appropraite here: Many standard algorithms and containers expect `<` to implement a [strict weak ordering](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). If your comparison doesn't do that and you still use it for such algorithms and containers your code will have undefined behavior.

That being said, algorithms arent magic, most of them are just a simple loop and not much more is needed here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

template <typename IT>
bool all_elems_compare_smaller(IT begin1,IT end1, IT begin2){
    for (; begin1 < end1;) {
        if (!(*begin1 < *begin2)) return false;
         ++begin1;
         ++begin2;
    }
    return true;
}


int main() {
    std::array<int,3> x{1,2,3};
    std::array<int,3> y{2,3,4};
    std::cout << all_elems_compare_smaller(x.begin(),x.end(),y.begin()) << "\n";
    std::cout << all_elems_compare_smaller(y.begin(),y.end(),x.begin()) << "\n";

}
```

Note for the sake of simplicity I didn't bother to allow a custom predicate, nor did I consider the possibility of iterators of different type. Moreover I think I actually got the comparison not exactly like you are asking for. I'll leave it to you to fix that ;)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no standard algorithm for exactly what you are asking for.  So, just write your own function for it, eg:

```cpp
template <typename T, size_t N>
bool AreAllElementsGreaterThan(const std::array<T, N> &a, const std::array<T, N> &b)
{
    for(size_t i = 0 i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (a[i] <= b[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```cpp
std::array<int,3> a{2,4,8};
std::array<int,3> b{1,2,3};

if (AreAllElementsGreaterThan(a, b)) {
    cout << "a is greater than b";
} else {
    cout << "a is not greater than b";
}

if (AreAllElementsGreaterThan(b, a)) {
    cout << "b is greater than a";
} else {
    cout << "b is not greater than a";
}
```